# Get Current month using `date` in Linux

Tags: linux, date, unix

I am trying to get current month based on date.
Till now it was working fine with below command -

```
cur_mon=`date --date="$report_date" '+%m' -d 'now'`
cur_year=`date --date="$report_date" '+%y' -d 'now'`
echo cur_mon and cur_year =${cur_mon} and ${cur_year}
```

$report_date is now 30th Sep 2014.

It is giving me output -
cur_mon and cur_year =**10** and 14

Let me know if anyone knows the reason as well solution.
Also this can also create problem in year. If date is 31st Dec, 2014.

Comment: Please explain why your output is incorrect, the month is October and the year is 2014 (here).

Comment: Perhaps you should check out the date man page.  If, for example, you want the whole year, not just two last digits, you should use %Y instead of %y.  In case you want month as abbreviated name, you should use %b instead of %m.

Comment: I am not using current date or system date. I am using date from $Report_date variable and its value is 30th Sep, 2014. It should return 9 as a current month not 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem, you are trying to describe your date twice.  Once with --date="$report_date" and second time with -d now.  Only the latter one is in effect.  That's why you see 10 instead of 9.

Comment: Seems you pointed correctly. But can you tell how can I use without --date because I want to use date which is in variable $report_date.echo $report_date
cur_mon=`date --date="$report_date" '+%m' -d 'now'`

Comment: Output for this is - 20140930
mon = 10

Comment: Simply leave one --date/-d out. `date --date="$report_date" '+%m'` will work just as `date -d "$report_date" '+%m'`

Answer (score -1):

Try `awk '{print $2}' <(date)` it should select the second element delimited by spaces in the output of date which is nominally month.